# Error when i try to opendir

Tags: perl, opendir

I am stuck on this piece of code. Maybe the cause is the accented characters inn the path, I don't know. The code that I'm using is below

```
my $var2 = realpath('C:\Users\brmelovi\Script\backups');
$source1 = 'N:\NBS_AR\COLLECTION\1.0 Times\2.0 Collections México\1. Macro de solicitação de Desglose';
$name1   = 'macro';

my $absol = path($source1)->absolute;
my @dire  = $absol->children( qr/^$name1/);
say $dire[0];
$dire[0]->copy($var2);

return 1;
```

The file and the path exist. My code already works with another path and name, like this

```
my $var2 = realpath('C:\Users\brmelovi\Script\backups');
$source1 = 'N:\NBS_AR\SISTEMAS AR\Macro Credit Analysis & Collection';
$name1   = 'Credit Analysis';

my $absol = path($source1) -> absolute;
my @dire  = $absol->children( qr/^$name1/);
say $dire[0];
$dire[0]->copy($var2);

return 1;
```

My header and `use` statements

```
use v5.28;
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use Cwd 'realpath';
use autodie;
use Path::Tiny;
```

The error message is

> Error opendir on 'N:/NBS_AR/COLLECTION/1.0 Times/2.0 Collections MΘxico/1. Macro de solicitaτπo de Desglose': No such file or directory at backup_script.pl line 24.

**Edit:**
Problem solved by the use of

```
use Encode::Local;
use Encode;
```

Thanks for the solution sticky bit.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I.e. put your code in the right order (`use` statements first), make sure it runs (no `return` outside of functions), etc.

Comment: What's line 24 of backup_script.pl?

Comment: Are you sure your source code file is saved as UTF8 encoding? Does the error disappear if you rename the file `1. Macro de solicitação de Desglose` to something without accents (and same of directory above it)?

Comment: As a general observation (i.e.: not suggesting this will fix this specific problem), I would recommend using forward slashes as a path separator rather than backslashes. It does work on Windows and does simplify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's probably the special characters in the path. At least I could reproduce the described behavior trying to `opendir()` a directory `1. Macro de solicitação de Desglose` in an UTF-8 encoded script on Windows.

Try to use [Encode::Locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Locale) to properly encode the string prior passing it to `opendir()`.

```
...
use Encode::Locale;
use Encode;
...
$source1 = encode(locale => 'N:\NBS_AR\COLLECTION\1.0 Times\2.0 Collections México\1. Macro de solicitação de Desglose');
...
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Man, this work for me, thanks A LOT, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: You can also use `encode("cp".Win32::GetACP(), $string)`

Comment: Yes, it looks like your editor is using a different encoding than Perl, which uses UTF-8.